# Input length of Sentence BERT

Tags: nlp, bert

Can Sentence Bert embed an entire paragraph instead of only a sentence? For example, a description of a movie.

If so, what if the word counts exceeded the input limit? I remember Bert can only take up to 512 tokens as inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since BERT is designed for a sentence it captures the context in a sentence.  However in a paragraph they will be number of sentences and a number of context.  it is not a good idea to insert paragraph in BERT.  you will not get good results
You should tokenize  paragraph in sentences using nltk  or spacy

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to embed a whole paragraph? should I take the mean of all sentences' embeddings in the paragraph?

Comment: Not sure but logically  The mean of embeddings should give information about the whole paragraph.